# How can I update LiveData<List> from another class?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata

So I have a list in my ViewModel that whenever suffers changes, they get reflected on the UI through DataBinding.

```
private val _entries = MutableLiveData<List<BarEntry>>()
val entries: LiveData<List<BarEntry>>
    get() = _entries
```

`ISortingAlgorithm` is an interface that represents a sorting algorithm.

```
interface ISortingAlgorithm
{
    fun sort(listToSort: List<BarEntry>)
}
```

Example (not the final implementation) of a concrete class implementing  `ISortingAlgorithm`:

```
class BubbleSort : ISortingAlgorithm
{
    override fun sort(listToSort: List<BarEntry>)
    {
        Log.d(this::class.java.canonicalName, "Applying sort")

        for(currentPass in 0 until (listToSort.size - 1))
        {
            for(currentPosition in 0 until (listToSort.size - currentPass - 1))
            {
                if(listToSort[currentPosition].y > listToSort[currentPosition + 1].y)
                {
                    val temp = listToSort[currentPosition].y
                    listToSort[currentPosition].y = listToSort[currentPosition+1].y
                    listToSort[currentPosition+1].y = temp
                }
                Thread.sleep(10)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In my ViewModel I have a `lateinit var sortingAlgorithm: ISortingAlgorithm`. When I call `sortingAlgorithm.sort(_entries.value)` I want the UI to reflect all the modifications done to the list at each step, not just the final result. How can this be done?

My solution right now is for `sort()` to return all the intermediate states of the list and then apply the changes to the original LiveData list in the viewmodel but this seems like a workaround not a solution.

Comment: Post the contents of SortingAlgorithm

Comment: Edited the original post.

Answer (score 0):

Build a LiveData using Kotlin extensions in your ViewModel.

```
lateinit var sorter: ISortingAlgorithm

fun getLiveData(listToSort: List<BarEntry>)
        : LiveData<List<BarEntry>> = androidx.lifecycle.liveData {
    emit(listToSort)
    while (sorter.sort(listToSort)) 
        emit(listToSort)
}
```

`sort()` can be modified to return a boolean that indicates whether a sort step just occurred. Sorting terminates when a step cannot occur.